# Firebase.initialize is not a function, am I missing a package?

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

I'm trying to create a firebase function which can access my database. However when I run **firebase deploy --only functions** I get the following error:

```
TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\TriviaGame\functions\index.js:34:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:21:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:75:3)
```

This is my code:

```
'use strict';


var firebase = require('firebase');
const {actionssdk} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = actionssdk({debug: true});


var config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database=firebase.database();
var allMyStuff = database.ref('triviagame');

//do stuff with my database values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm install firebase` in my functions directory, updated my packages and gave me access to the `initializeApp()` function.